# Firebase on Android: How to check Firebase auth failed reason?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase on Android and Firebase Auth functions.

I try `FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` and in case it fails I want to know why the signIn process failed?

The `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method has `addOnFailureListener` API.
And I can catch the `Exception`(maybe `FirebaseAuthException`) in `onFailure` callback method.

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginRequest.id, loginRequest.password)
  .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
      if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthException) {
        ((FirebaseAuthException) e).getErrorCode());
      }
    }
  });
```

I want to know why the SignIn process failed. in `onFailure`.

I think it could be done as follows:

1. `e` instance type check(e instanceOf `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException` or `FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException` or ,,,)
2. `e.getErrorCode()`

I do not want to type checks (it's dirty).
I prefer the way in choice 2. above. But I could not find the definition of `e.getErrorCode()` return values collection.
e.g `ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL`, `ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL`, etc.
(Where are they defined?)

How do I find out why Firebase auth failed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was having the same doubts and I found a bit more information on their documentation.

For example in you are using this method **createUserWithEmailAndPassword** you can see on their [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signInWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) the following exceptions:

Exceptions:

FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException thrown if the password is not strong enough
FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException thrown if the email address is malformed
FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException thrown if there already exists an account with the given email address

For each exception there is also a documentation page, for example the one for [FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException)

And here you can see the different error types:

> ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE when trying to create a new account with createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String, String) or to change a user's email address, if the email is already in use by a different account
>
> ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL when calling signInWithCredential(AuthCredential) with a credential that asserts an email address in use by another account. This error will only be thrown if the "One account per email address" setting is enabled in the Firebase console (recommended).
>
> ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE when trying to link a user with an AuthCredential corresponding to another account already in use

So if you do a getErrorCode() and compare the string with any of these Constants you will know exactly the cause of the exception.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 15):

I found some codes inside Firebase library which is similar to the failure messages have seen so far. But havent tried yet. You can give it a try.

```
    ("ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN", "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."));
    ("ERROR_CUSTOM_TOKEN_MISMATCH", "The custom token corresponds to a different audience."));
    ("ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL", "The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired."));
    ("ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL", "The email address is badly formatted."));
    ("ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD", "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password."));
    ("ERROR_USER_MISMATCH", "The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user."));
    ("ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN", "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request."));
    ("ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL", "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address."));
    ("ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE", "The email address is already in use by another account."));
    ("ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE", "This credential is already associated with a different user account."));
    ("ERROR_USER_DISABLED", "The user account has been disabled by an administrator."));
    ("ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED", "The user\'s credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again."));
    ("ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND", "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."));
    ("ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN", "The user\'s credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again."));
    ("ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED", "This operation is not allowed. You must enable this service in the console."));
    ("ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD", "The given password is invalid."));
```

Comment: Is there any public static String constants available for those error codes? (e.g. FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE)

Comment: i dont think so. proper implementation is as in @Lancelot's answer. and your 1st option. It is not dirty and better to handle each exception seperately. even if you choose 2nd you are gonna handle each case. it seems same amount of code.

Comment: Thanks for your info, though I guess having String constant value declared is much safer and easier compared to typing string value by yourself, as auto complete will save your time if the constant is already declared, and mistyping can happen if you need to write those strings by yourself.

Comment: Seems to be coming from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/93c8b48269e42d1f5f116d7a54ad55d7dfa4c9fd/firebase-common/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/FirebaseError.java

Answer (score 0):

Once you successfully enabled the email+password auth method you will need to create an application for your Firebase project to work.

Go to:
Overview -> Add another App -> Follow the next steps according to your needs.

Hope it helps everybody. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It used to be necessary to translate from Strings to a proper error message, but since firebase-admin 7.3.0 this is done by [AuthErrorHandler](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/auth/internal/AuthErrorHandler.java) and you should be able to just invoke `FirebaseAuthException.getMessage()`

If you still want to build this, `FirebaseAuthException.getAuthErrorCode()` will return an instance of [`AuthErrorCode`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthErrorCode.java), which is now an enum.