# How to get Firebase Exception into a switch statement

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I currently have this code:

```
if (!task.isSuccessful() && task.getException() != null) {
   FirebaseCrash.report(task.getException());
   Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
   Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Authentication failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Sometimes a user gets a `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException`, and I want to detect it in a `switch` statement like so:

```
switch(task.getException()){
    case /*I don't know what goes here*/:
       //Whatever
}
```

But as you read, I don't know what to put in the `case` statement. What do I put in there? In other words, where is the `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException` located so I can access it? `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException` is just a class so I can't currently do anything with it.

Comment: The same issue is [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37859582/4815718).  As I see things, there is no simple and clean way to do what you want.  In addition to the approaches presented in the answers here, you also can consider [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38490022/4815718).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication exceptions all derive from [`FirebaseAuthException`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException), which has a [`getErrorCode()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException.html#getErrorCode()) method.

So:

```
if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthException){
    FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException)task.getException();
    switch (e.getErrorCode()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how do I get "FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException"? `case "FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException":`?

Comment: A switch case cannot test classes in Java. If you want a switch case, you'll need to compare against `getErrorCode()`. If you want to compare against the class, you'll need to nest `if`s as @rafal says.

Comment: Fine, but how DO I compare the class? And if that's true, why did you include `switch(e.getErrorCode())` in your answer? Love your answers btw, very useful :)

Comment: rafal's answer shows how to compare exception classes. If that doesn't work for you, show the code of how you did it (by editing your question).

Comment: Frank:  The [documentation for FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) contains identifiers for error code string constants (e.g. `ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE`), but these don't seem to be accessible as public members of some class.  Am I not looking hard enough?  An industrious developer found this [table of constants](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38038392/4815718) in a Firebase library.

Comment: @BobSnyder same here; it seems like Firebase library currently does not provide us public string constant error codes, so we may need to hardcode those string values.. which can be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException){
    //whatever
}
```

Comment: if other exception is a subclass of this exception class it would fall into this if aswell.